# Serialize Json Array with Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, jsonserializer

Could someone helpe me?

How can I code 'Shippings' class as an Array to get the json example below?

```json
{
  "seller_id": "123",
  "amount": 100,
  "order": {
    "order_id": "1111",
    "sales_tax": 0,
    "product_type": "service"
  },
  "shippings": [{
    "first_name": "John",
    "phone_number": "5551999887766",
    "shipping_amount": 3000,
    "address": {
      "street": "Street 35 Conts",
      "number": "1000",
      "complement": "ap1",
      "postal_code": "90230060"
    }
  }],
  "credit": {
    "delayed": false,
    "authenticated": false
  }
}
```

I am doing this below, using asp.net mvc, but don't know how to get Shippings as Array [].

Can someone give me some exemplo or anything else... I'll appreciate.

```
var request = new GetNetRoot() {
  SellerId = seller_id,
    Amount = orderItens.Amount
  Order = new GetNetPagOrder() {
      OrderId = order.id.ToString(),
        SalesTax = orderItens.Tax,
        ProductType = orderItens.ProdType
    },
    Shippings = new GetNetPagShippings() {
      FirstName = "",
        PhoneNumber = usr.PhoneNumber,
        ShippingAmount = orderItens.AmountShip,
        Address = new GetNetPagAddress() {
          Street = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.IdRuaNavigation.Nome,
            Number = catEnd.NumEndereco,
            Complement = catEnd.Complemento,
            PostalCode = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.Cep
        }
    },
    Credit = new GetNetPagCredit() {
      Delayed = false,
        Authenticated = false
    }
};

var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)
```

Comment: _Edit-Paste Special-Paste JSON as classes_ menu item in visual studio to get a proper class model. `GetNetPagShippings` should return an array, not the single item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize Shippings like an array:

```
Shippings = new[] {
    new GetNetPagShippings()
    {
        FirstName = "",                              
        PhoneNumber = usr.PhoneNumber,
        ShippingAmount = orderItens.AmountShip,
        Address = new GetNetPagAddress()
        {
            Street = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.IdRuaNavigation.Nome,       
            Number = catEnd.NumEndereco,                                                
            Complement = catEnd.Complemento,                                           
            PostalCode = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.Cep                      
        }
    }



public class GetNetPagamentoRoot
{
    ...

    public GetNetPagShippings[] Shippings { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array initializer syntax. Simplistic example would be array of int:

```cs
int[] myArray = new [] { 1, 2, 3 }
```

In your code `Shippings` should be initialized as an array.

```cs
var request = new GetNetRoot()
{
    SellerId = seller_id,
    Amount = orderItens.Amount
    Order = new GetNetPagOrder()
    {
        OrderId = order.id.ToString(),
        SalesTax =  orderItens.Tax,
        ProductType =  orderItens.ProdType
    },
    // Array initializer with 2 elements.
    Shippings = new[] {
        new GetNetPagShippings()
        {
            FirstName = "",                              
            PhoneNumber = usr.PhoneNumber,
            ShippingAmount = orderItens.AmountShip,
            Address = new GetNetPagAddress()
            {
                Street = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.IdRuaNavigation.Nome,       
                Number = catEnd.NumEndereco,                                                
                Complement = catEnd.Complemento,                                           
                PostalCode = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.Cep                      
            }
        },
        new GetNetPagShippings()
        {
            FirstName = "",                              
            PhoneNumber = usr.PhoneNumber,
            ShippingAmount = orderItens.AmountShip,
            Address = new GetNetPagAddress()
            {
                Street = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.IdRuaNavigation.Nome,       
                Number = catEnd.NumEndereco,                                                
                Complement = catEnd.Complemento,                                           
                PostalCode = catEnd.IdEnderecoLogradouroNavigation.Cep                      
            }
        }
    },
    Credit = new GetNetPagCredit()
    {
        Delayed = false,
        Authenticated = false
    }
};

var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GetNetRoot outer class needs to define the "Shippings" property as a list or array of the GetNetPagShippings class as opposed to a single instance. When you serialize it to JSON, it will be represented as a JSON array of the object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClassInstance = new MyOuterClass()
            {
                OuterProperty = "Outer Property",
                MyInnerClassList = new List<MyInnerClass>()
                {
                    new MyInnerClass()
                    {
                        InnerProperty = "Inner Property Item 1"
                    },
                    new MyInnerClass()
                    {
                        InnerProperty = "Inner Property Item 2"
                    }
                }
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClassInstance);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }

    public class MyOuterClass
    {
        public string OuterProperty { get; set; }
        public List<MyInnerClass> MyInnerClassList { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyInnerClass
    {
        public string InnerProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```